# importing from parent directory

Tags: python

I have this kind of path architecture :

```
>main_path/  
    __init__.py  
    config/  
        __init__.py  
        common.py  
    app_1/  
        __init__.py  
        config.py  
        index.py
>
```

I'd like to be able to do so in `config.py` :

```
>from main_path.config import common
>
```

Though it does not work. Python tells me :

```
> $> pwd
..../main_path/app_1  
$> python index.py
[...]  
ImportError: No module named main_path.config
>
```

As far as I understand, this would be possible if i loaded everything up from the main_path, though the aim is to have multiple apps with a common config file.
I tried to add the parent directory to the `__path__` in the app_1/`__init__`.py but it changed nothing.

My next move would be to have a symbolic link, though I don't really like this "solution", so if you have any idea to help me out, this would be much appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Modules documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) a module has to be in your PYTHONPATH environment variable to be imported.  You can modify this within your program with something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('PATH_TO/config')
import common
```

For more information, you may want to see [Modifying Python's Search Path](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path) in [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html).

Comment: If you're using relative imports, you could also do `import os; os.chdir('PATH_TO/config')` if you felt like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify python's search path without having to set PYTHONPATH each time, you can add a path configuration file (.pth file) to a directory that is already on the python path.

This document describes it in detail: http://docs.python.org/install/#inst-search-path

> The most convenient way is to add a
>   path configuration file to a directory
>   that’s already on Python’s path,
>   usually to the .../site-packages/
>   directory. Path configuration files
>   have an extension of .pth, and each
>   line must contain a single path that
>   will be appended to sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your PYTHONPATH environment variable or edit sys.path.