# Error with relative parent imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

**I'm running into an error when attempting to import a file in the parent directory.**

Code from `test/log_line.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from ..lib_common import log_line
```

Error:

```
$ py -3 test/log_line.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/log_line.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .. import lib_common
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Directory Structure:

```
./
|   test/
|   |   log_line.py
|   lib_common.py
|   __init__.py
```

`lib_common.py` contains the `log_line` function.
Added `__init__.py` at the suggestion of @Pavel.

Any idea why Python is giving me the error? Googling the traceback returned one somewhat-related result. No luck.

Comment: Create an empty file named `__init__.py` in `./`

Comment: @Pavel Didn't solve it.

Comment: Even with `__init__.py` in the root it won't work because you're making `test` as your entry point. It's a bad design anyway, why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @zwer Because I didn't know of another way. Enlighten me, what is the better way?

Comment: Start importing from your parent dictionary and work down.

Comment: @spikespaz - do not import from children back to their parents (in package structure) do it other way around, as expected by Python.

Comment: @Simon If `from .. import lib_common` is what you mean, that doesn't help either.

Comment: No I meant put `log_line.py` in the parent and `lib_common.py` in a subfolder

Comment: @Simon `lib_common.py` shouldn't be in the `test/` directory because it needs to be used by other files in the parent package.

Comment: Damn you've really messed yourself up.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668729/python-import-from-parent-directory may be of some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python import from parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668729/python-import-from-parent-directory)